# Unable to run docker build inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, rhel7

On doing docker build inside Jenkinsfile,
i.e

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t datastore:1.0.1 .
```

I am getting error like

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This is my Jenkinsfile

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy


node {
    checkout scm

    // Here are the important data for this build
    def DOCKER_REGISTRY = "XXX"
    def DATASTORE = "datastore"
    def DOCKER_TAG_DATASTORE = "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/XXX"
    def APP_VERSION = "1.0.1"

    stage('Build') {
        dockerInside('XXX/db-server:1.0.114', '') {

            echo "Setting up artifactory location to push docker image ${DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION}"
            sh "docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t ${DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION} ."
            sh "docker tag ${DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION} ${DOCKER_TAG_DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION}"
            withCredentials([
                            usernamePassword(
                                credentialsId:    CORE_IZ_USER,
                                usernameVariable: 'LOG',
                                passwordVariable: 'PAS'
                        )]) {
                            // Doing some upload commands (see artifactory or docker upload commands from Jenkins)
                            sh "docker push ${DOCKER_TAG_DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION}"
                            echo "Push to ${DOCKER_TAG_DATASTORE}:${APP_VERSION}"
                        }
        }
    }

    stage('Docker image creation') {
      echo "Docker image creation"
    }

    stage('Docker image upload') {

        echo "Docker image upload"
    }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM XXX/rhel:7.5

USER root
RUN yum -y install gcc && yum install -y git && yum install -y docker

# Install Go

RUN curl -O -s https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf go1.10.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local

ENV PATH /usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
ENV GOPATH /gopath
ENV GOBIN /usr/local/go/bin

WORKDIR /gopath/src/XXX
RUN mkdir -p /gopath/src/XXX
ADD . /gopath/src/XXX

RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -tags netgo -installsuffix netgo -o ./db-server /gopath/src/XXX/datastore/main.go
ADD ./db-server /db-server
ENTRYPOINT ["/db-server"]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I can only guess what is the `dockerInside` custom step in your pipeline. But it looks like you are trying to run docker inside docker with an image apparently meant for a db server. This probably explains why you get the crystal clear question right after your very relevant error message: `Is the docker daemon running?`.

Comment: But I am installing docker in the Dockerfile in order to avoid the docker daemon error. Still I am getting the ```Is the docker daemon running?```
I even tried adding 
```RUN  systemctl start docker and RUN systemctl enable docker``` in my Dockerfile to start my docker daemon, but still it doesn't work.
Are you saying that I cannot run docker daemon inside a docker image?

Comment: An image is not running anything: it's an image. You can eventually run a docker daemon while building the image (I don't see why it would be usefull...) but it will stop when the image is done building. You need to run the docker daemon in your **container** (eg from ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD). Enabling with systemctl might work only if the container is starting systemd which is usually not the case. Moreover, you have to run your container priviliged and mount special filesystems. Old article but good start: https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/